# Implementing a factory: ObjectGraph.get(T.class) vs. Lazy<T>

Tags: dagger

I've got a factory that relies on a call-stack variable to select which type to build. I'd like that Dagger injections would be provided for the built instance and its descendants, without having to actually build all the possible instances in advance, but just the one that is actually selected by the factory. I came up with the following alternatives:

**Using ObjectGraph.get()**

```
class Factory {  
  FooInterface create(FooTypeEnum type) {
    switch(type) {
      case TYPE_A:
        return objectGraph.get(FooA.class);
        break;
      case TYPE_B:
        return objectGraph.get(FooB.class);
        break;      
    }
  }
}
```

**Using Lazy** (the factory can itself be injected by Dagger)

```
class Factory {
  @Inject Lazy<FooA> fooA;
  @Inject Lazy<FooB> fooB;

  FooInterface create(FooTypeEnum type) {
    switch(type) {
      case TYPE_A:
        return fooA.get();
        break;
      case TYPE_B:
        return fooB.get();
        break;      
    }
  }
}
```

Pros, cons, other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prefer the second one, since it explicitly states its dependencies, rather than asking for the whole `ObjectGraph`. But you probably meant to inject `Provider<T>`, not `Lazy<T>`, in order to match the behavior of `ObjectGraph.get`.